# Recursive sequence with dependence of $n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

After consideration on monotony of the sequence, I want to find the result of $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ in case it is a recursive sequence like: $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)=\sqrt{\frac{n^2+1}{n^2+3}}x_n$.
In this case the argument for which if $l=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$ then $f(l)=l$ does not work. All $l$ are possible . . . what I should do in cases like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we would need an initial value $x_0$ if we were to get an exact solution to your problem. But lets just consider arbitrary $x_0$.

Notice that,
$$\begin{align}
x_{n+1} &= \prod_{k=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{k^2+1}{k^2+3}}x_0,\\
        &= x_0\sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^2+1}{k^2+3}},\\
&= x_0\sqrt{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1+\frac{1}{k^2}}{1+\frac{3}{k^2}}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Next due to Euler or Weierstrass we know that $\sin(\pi z) = \pi z\prod_{k=1}^\infty\big(1-\frac{z^2}{k^2}\big)$. Thus by sending $n$ to infinity and setting $z=i$ and $z=i\sqrt3$ would allow us to conclude the result. All that is left to do are the calculations.

Comment: Personally I would credit Weierstrass with the product formula for $\sin$, but good answer anyway.

Comment: So in cases like that I should find the explicit expression for $x_n$?

Comment: @K.defaoite I'm not too sure who I should credit but I'll edit it to add him.

Comment: @willie if you have this sort of sequence then taking it a an infinite product would be a good idea.

Comment: @MilosTasic Ok thanks!